# Mac equivalent of Ctrl + Space to select an item on a list

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

I want to select non-consecutive items on a list, **without using a mouse/trackpad** - there should be no *clicks* involved.

In Windows and Linux (at least Ubuntu) an item can be selected using <kbd>Space/</kbd> button, which, in combination with arrows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key allows me to select multiple items in any environment (file manager, IDE etc.) - e.g.

Enter a directory -> hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -> down arrow twice -> press <kbd>Space</kbd> -> down arrow twice -> press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Now I should have items 1, 3 and 5 selected.
Is there a way to do the same thing in OS X?

PS. Sorry for such a verbose description, but so far every answer I encountered advices using <kbd>Command</kbd> + Click, and this is something I **don't** want to do.

Comment: Command-Click selects non-consecutive items, so it would intuitively follow that you would Command instead of Control for the functionality you want - however Command-Down Arrow opens the selected file/application, and Space opens QuickLook. The end result is what you are asking is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a native way to do this, but if you install [Shortcat](https://shortcatapp.com) you can:

- select the first item using arrow keys
- activate Shortcat and type enough to focus on the next item you want
- hold Command and press Return

By the way, if you're as keyboard-centric as I am, you should also look at [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).

Answer (score 2):

There is a native way using Accessibility to emulate mouse click as a "I" key

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18381?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

> Option-Command-F5

then select

> Enable Mouse Keys